# name json variable and jsonString variable convention?

Tags: json

JSON could mean JSON type or json string.
It starts confuse me when different library use json in two different meanings.

I wonder how other people name those variables differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all practical purposes, "JSON" has exactly one meaning, which is a *string* representing a JavaScript object following certain specific syntax.

JSON is parsed into a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse`, and an JavaScript object is converted into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify`.

The problem is that all too many people have gotten into the bad habit of referring to plain old JavaScript objects as JSON. That is either confused or sloppy or both. `{a: 1}` is a JS object. `'{"a": 1}'` is a JSON string.

In the same vein, many people use variable names like `json` to refer to JavaScript objects derived from JSON. For example:

```
$.getJSON('foo.php') . then(function(json) { ...
```

In the above case, the variable name `json` is ill-advised. The actual payload returned from the server is a JSON string, but internally `$.getJSON` has already transformed that into a plain old JavaScript object, which is what is being passed to the `then` handler. Therefore, it would be preferable to use the variable name `data`, for example.

If a library uses the term "json" to refer to things which are not JSON, but actually are JavaScript objects, it is a mark of poor design, and I'd suggest looking around for a different library.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.. Android uses `JsonObject` and iOS 's famous swift json library uses `JSON` as a type (that acts as a dictionary you can pull data from by something like `jsonObject.get("name")`  ..